# How to remove tags in spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, spyder

Am using BeautifulSoup for web scraping, i want to remove the header tags from the output.

Here is my code:

```
job_location = first_job.find('div', class_ = 'columns end large-2 medium-3 small-12')  
job_location

first_job_location = job_location.h4

first_job_location
```

Result:

```
Out[102]: 

<
h4 class=
"job-text">

Miami, FL

<
/h4>
```

Desired output should be only: Miami, FL

I have tried using .text but still the out put is same.

please guide.